# Parallel read and write to postgres database slows down application (backend)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have a backend in nestjs using typeorm and postgres. This backend saves and reads data frequently from the database. In this database we are dealing with row counts of 10k + at times that needs to get updated and saved or created.

In this particular case where I need some brain juice I have a table (lets call it table a)

the backend fetches data from table a every few seconds

the content in table A needs to get updated frequently (properties and values overwritten). I am doing this updating task from a several application backend solely for this use-case.

Example case
Table A holds 100K records
update-service splits these 100K records into chunks of 5 and parallell updates 25K records each. While doing so, the main application that retrieves data from the backend slows down.

What is the best way to have performant read and write in parallel? I am assuming the slow down comes from locks (main backend retrieves data while update service tries to update) but I am not sure as I have not that much experience working with databases.

Comment: Reading and updating the same records at the same time is not a problem. Two processes trying to update the same record, is a problem, the second proces has to wait. Usually IO is the culprit, but without any information about the behaviour of your server and your database, this is just an educated guess. Changing the fill factor for your tables might help to speed up the updated, but it all depends...

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume, assert.

While you experiencing bad performance, check how the operating system's resources are doing; in this case, mostly CPU and disk. If one of them is maxed out, you know what is going on, and you either have to reduce the degree of parallelism or make the system stronger.

It is also interesting to look at wait events in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT wait_event_type, wait_event, count(*)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active'
GROUP BY wait_event_type, wait_event;
```

That will show I/O related events if you are running out of disk bandwidth, but it will also show database-internal contention that you can potentially hit with very high degrees of parallelism.

Comment: thank you for that tip. I ran that query, dont get any result so the count is at 0. I will check system resources now. If its important to know, all of this is running inside docker containers on a t2 large instance on aws

Comment: The count will never be 0, as you will always at least see the query itself executing.

Comment: I have wait event type null, wait_event null, count 1, sometimes count goes up to 7 when I repeat refresh

Comment: Then you may be CPU bound. Do as I suggested and measure on the operating system.

Comment: cpu capps at arround 40% at my aws, memory also not critical.  

all I am doing is select data from table a  while another app is inserting and updating to table a. But on a larger scale as I said initially. Sometimes one process updates 25K items while another one is updating 10k. If I do this task sequentially its not slowing down the app but that would take forever for all data to get updated multiple times a day

Comment: Then the bottleneck may not be on the database at all, but elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any overlap between this set of 25k records and the set of 10k records? Just a single record that is in both sets, will block one of these processes.